# Talend Open Studio: maven to add librairies

Tags: maven, talend

TOS for Data Integration version: 6.3.0

Let's says there's a routine that needs a external lib (i.e. commons lang).

I would like to make maven download this lib (I don't want to add it manually with right click, add etc..).

The goal is to make the project more 'team friendly'.

I tried to modify the pom dependencies here: 'project properties' > build > Maven > Default > Project

But is doesn't work.

Any idea how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use tLibraryLoad.
[image]

You may also be able to put the tLibraryLoad in a joblet along with other initialization items, and make using the joblet a standard part of each job template so that individual developers do not have to put thought into it. We do that for out initialization items, but I have not tried it with a tLibraryLoad.

Comment: This doesn't make the library available for Java classes defined in Talend. Is there any way to make Maven update the dependencies and make them available to Java classes?

Comment: don't know, haven't had a need to try that.